# PHP function call not working

Tags: php

I would like to print out the values from the return function, my main aim is to call the function from a different file which i have done several times with different functions, but this doesn't seems to work and I cant figure it out. Please help.

swifty.php

```
    include_once('core/init.php');
    $errorno = 'Please contact the administrator, Quoting err no : q2913, Q Issues referring to: ' . mysqli_error($con);

    function getStatus_update() {
        $user_id = (int) $user_data['id'];
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users_status WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id` ORDER BY `date_posted` DESC'");
        $update = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $update[] = $row;
        }return $update;
    }
```

user.php

```
<?php
include_once 'swifty.php';
$rand = getStatus_update();

        foreach ($rand as $k => $v) {
            var_dump($v['status']);
        }
```

Nothing happens, no error messages, no values returned.

Comment: What happens if you run `var_dump($rand)` before the foreach?

Comment: Neither `$user_data` nor `$con` are in [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) within the `getStatus_update()` function

Comment: I see a single quote followed by a double quote at the end of your query, is that intended? Perhaps you meant "SELECT * FROM users_status WHERE `user_id` = '{$user_id}' ORDER BY 'date_posted' DESC"

Comment: In these cases, keep calm and enable [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/it/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: If i remove the function and var_dump the array, then i get the expected result, but in a function it isn't working, the included path to the php file is accurate, i also called the function within thesame file and it still not working, I have corrected the `$user_id to `$user_id` and it still not working.the ini.php contains the $user_data; and $con which works fine.

Comment: @MarkBaker wide open to sql injection as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `$user_data` nor `$con` are in [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) within the `getStatus_update()` function

```
include_once('core/init.php');
$errorno = 'Please contact the administrator, Quoting err no : q2913, Q Issues referring to: ' . mysqli_error($con);

function getStatus_update($con, $user_data) {
    $user_id = (int) $user_data['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users_status WHERE `user_id` = '{$user_id}' ORDER BY `date_posted` DESC");
    $update = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $update[] = $row;
    }
    return $update;
}
```

and

```
$rand = getStatus_update($con, $user_data);

foreach ($rand as $k => $v) {
    var_dump($v['status']);
}
```

And if you're just starting to learn PHP, learn to use bind variables in your SQL queries as well

Comment: I believe the query is also wrong , it should be {$user_id}.

Comment: It's been so long since I used variable injection directly into an SQL query, I sometimes forget how to do it.... though the quotes shouldn't be necessary anyway as `$user_id` is being cast to an integer

Comment: Happens to everyone Mark :-)

Comment: @MartinSnitram `$user_id` is clearly undefined, as you seem to be accessing an array that doesn't exist inside the local scope of the function. check your error logs. also read up on variable scoping.

Comment: @r3wt - `$user_id` is in scope in `getStatus_update()`, because it's assigned from `$user_data` which is being passed as an argument in my above

Comment: @MartinSnitram - if it's still not working, try doing a bit of elementary debugging, such as var_dumping $user_data before calling getStatus_update(); put some error handling in your code in case the SQL query fails, etc

Comment: @MarkBaker ok my bad, but i'm pretty sure that interpolation inside SQL Query syntax is deprecated. think you have to do `'".$variable."'` but i'm not 100% on that.

Comment: Sadly, interpolation inside SQL Query syntax isn't deprecated... this interpolation is purely standard PHP string interpolation

Comment: It turns out, session had been terminated, forgot to add a redirect once users session times out in the php file, so the whole time user_id was not available. fail.com, mine one doesnt work even while user is signed in. So mark code definitely does work, thanks all for your input

Answer (score 0):

You also may want to set the include path